# How to authenticate with Active Directory in HeidiSQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, heidisql

Anyone also using this nifty little client?

https://www.heidisql.com/

[image]

It works on databases hosted on the local but it is unable to connect to the server on Azure via Active Directory.

SQL Server 12.0.2000.8

Comment: Not sure this question is related to SQL Server.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the author of HeidiSQL is interested in supporting AzAD, ref: [Support for 'Active Directory Authentication with password'](https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=25690), they didn't even ask the op for more information or testing assistance.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Hey thanks. That's too bad.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Azure Active Directory authentication isn't supported for HeidiSQL. You only need to use standard username and password approach.

You can raise a feature request [here](https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?post_action=add) but since HeidiSQL is not a widely used tool and also their community is not so strong, this would be difficult to say if they will roll out this feature in future.

Comment: I did request it in the forum but it appears the dev is not interested. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately  :(